# Armstrong Ultra SX90 Furnace problem

Tags: hvac

We have an Armstrong Ultra SX90 Furnace that the fan stops running when it's on cool but constantly runs when it's on heat. We have tried everything but replace circuit board. Any help wd be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Has anything changed (new thermostat, etc.)?   When is the last time you changed the filter?  You said "*the fan stops running when it's on cool*". Does that mean that it stops in the middle of a cooling cycle, or that when you flip the switch on the thermostat to `COOL` the fan stops?

Comment: The fan constantly running when in heating mode, points to either it being wired that way, or an open limit switch in the furnace.

Comment: When you flip the switch to cool. The fan stops. Air was running and fan suddenly stopped. We were testing it and turned heat on and fan works fine but will not shut off set on auto.

Comment: Can you post photos of the thermostat wiring at the thermostat, and at the furnace?  Do you have a multimeter, and are you willing to poke around in an HVAC system?  If the fan is not on when the thermostat is calling for cool (that's calling for cool, not just set to the `COOL` setting), then it's possible that one of the fan speeds is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Even though HVAC is not my specialty (electrical is), I have worked on HVAC controls for Energy Management Systems. As far as I know all heat units have a cool down cycle so when the heat turns off the fan continues to run to *softly* cool down the unit. This could either be a timing relay or thermo sensor which tells the fan it can shut down.

So that's where I would look. My thinking is that this devices is bad and faulted to a *normally on position* where the fan is running all the time. As a DIYer I don't think it wise to get into HVAC controls unless you had some experience and are good at following schematics and finding part numbers for replacement. I am suggesting a qualified HVAC mechanic should be doing this repair.

Good luck and stay safe.